# how to make a login page outside the single page application in angular js

Tags: node.js, angular

I have an angularJS single page application. It is an admin dashboard. However I do not want anyone to access the dashboard unless he is logged in.

Comment: This is way too broad to be asked here. Please take the [tour] and look through the [help]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask You need to show what you've attempted and what specific problems you face. What backend are you using? What is maintaining sessions etc?

Answer (score 0):

This is extremely broad. But you can look into route guards and canActivate from angular. Very similar between angularjs and 2/4. https://angular.io/api/router/CanActivate